# Sticky UICollectionViewHeader incorrect y origin point when footer is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` which has a sticky header using a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. The `UICollectionView` contains photos, and when scrolled past a certain point, a footer view is displayed with an activity indicator until more photos are loaded. If a user scrolls quickly through the photos and reaches the footer view, the `UICollectionView` header's y origin becomes incorrect and the header jumps to an incorrect position, until the photos are loaded. I want to get rid of that jump. Here is the custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        // Create a sticky UICollectionView Header
        var answer: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)! as [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        let contentOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset

        let missingSections = NSMutableIndexSet()

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == .Cell) {
                missingSections.addIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    missingSections.removeIndex(layoutAttributes.indexPath.section)
                }
            }
        }

        missingSections.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock { idx, stop in
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: idx)
            if let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: indexPath) {
                answer.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        }

        for layoutAttributes in answer {
            if let representedElementKind = layoutAttributes.representedElementKind {
                if representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
                    let section = layoutAttributes.indexPath.section
                    let numberOfItemsInSection = collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)

                    let firstCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)
                    let lastCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: max(0, (numberOfItemsInSection - 1)), inSection: section)

                    var cellExists: Bool = false
                    let (firstCellAttributes, lastCellAttributes): (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) = {
                        if (self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0) {
                            cellExists = true
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(firstCellIndexPath)!,
                                self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(lastCellIndexPath)!)
                        } else {
                            cellExists = false
                            return (
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, atIndexPath: firstCellIndexPath)!,
                                self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, atIndexPath: lastCellIndexPath)!)
                        }
                    }()

                    let topHeaderHeight = cellExists ? CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame) : 0
                    let bottomHeaderHeight = CGRectGetHeight(layoutAttributes.frame)
                    let frameWithEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(layoutAttributes.frame, collectionView!.contentInset)

                    var origin = frameWithEdgeInsets.origin

                    origin.y = min(max(contentOffset.y + collectionView!.contentInset.top,
                        (CGRectGetMinY(firstCellAttributes.frame) - topHeaderHeight - self.sectionInset.top))
                        ,(CGRectGetMaxY(lastCellAttributes.frame) - bottomHeaderHeight + self.sectionInset.bottom))

                    layoutAttributes.zIndex = 1024
                    layoutAttributes.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: layoutAttributes.frame.size)
                }
            }
        }

        return answer
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what modifications can be made to ensure the header doesn't jump when the footer view becomes visible?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to generate a fix for it. I used a static view for the header instead.